# "Conflicing values set for option Trusted regarding source ..." when running apt-get update

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-sources

I am a ubuntu new user. I need help, I can't run `sudo apt-get update` on my linux. Any suggestion for me?

[image]

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, why does your message imply you are running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (ie. *precise*) ??

Comment: Have you manually added some of the lines in the ```/etc/apt/sources.list``` file?

Comment: That file in a vanilla ubuntu should look like [this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/5TJd4s4pcs/).After modifying that , run ```sudo apt update``` again.And please avoid using images when you can just copy-paste the contents(i.e when they're merely textual).